# Get HP Product Number via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have put together a robust HP Warrant Lookup PowerShell script. However, I cannot figure out how to get a HP system's product number in an automated process. So...

How can I get HP product number (not the serial number) via PowerShell? Although I would like to do with only built-in out-of-the-box Windows and PowerShell commands, I am open to other ideas. In the end, the ultimate goal is retrieve the product number in the most reliable and least invasive way possible (i.e. installing 3rd software).

**Troubleshooting**

Tried:

`Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object OEMStringArray`

Result:

`{ABS 70/71 79 7A 7B 7C, CMS v01.4A, HP_Mute_LED_0, www.hp.com}`

... But expecting to find `XT908UT#ABA`

Comment: Is the product number you were expecting listed when running either of the following commands? `wmic csproduct list /format:list` / `wmic computersystem list /format:list`

Comment: Nope. I am pretty sure it's stored in SMBios, but I don't know a reliable way to retrieve it.

Comment: [This article](http://www.danielfortier.com/?p=281) says that the number is in the registry at `HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS\SystemSKU` so can be retrieved in PowerShell. [This one](http://myitforum.com/myitforumwp/2012/01/10/getting-the-hp-product-number-and-serial-number/) says `wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi path MS_SystemInformation`. Does any of these work for you?

Comment: On a Dell computer I can use `Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS | Select-Object SerialNumber` (I have no HP to test this on).

Comment: @harrymc - Looks like the registry and MS_SystemInformation is a go! Thanks, you should post it answer answer. I am disappointed in myself because I did come across the same article (registry method) but blew it off.

Comment: Answer is posted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some methods that work for various computer models.

**Method 1 : Registry**

The HP product number is in the registry so can be retrieved in PowerShell
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS`
item `SystemSKU`.

More information and script can be found in the article :
[How to: Find the HP Product Number of all your HP server using powershell](http://www.danielfortier.com/?p=281).

**Method 2 : root\wmi – MS_SystemInformation**

Class MS_SystemInformation contains the product number in its member `SystemSKU`.
(Presumably it gets it from the registry as in the first method.)

For more info see [Richard Siddaway's Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/richardsiddaway/archive/2011/05/26/root-wmi-ms-systeminformation.aspx).

**Method 3 : Class Win32_BIOS**

The following fragment finds the product number for some computer makes. Tested on Dell.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS | Select-Object SerialNumber
```

The Microsoft reference information is found in the article [Win32_BIOS class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The Win32_BIOS class does have the serial number, but that's different than HP's product number (P/N). Which I have recently discovered is call System SKU by Microsoft and Product SKU by SMBios. The registry and MS_SystemInformation class does store this P/N I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is tested on a HP Laptop. I think HP "Product number" is called SystemSKUNumber in win32_computersystem WMI. Tested on my HP laptop.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem | Select-Object SystemSKUNumber
```

Will result in:

```
SystemSKUNumber
---------------
J9A12EA#ABN
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this question, be advised, the entirety of win32_computersystem doesn't appear to contain the product number for servers, specifically. I was unable to actually find the information via WMI, but it turns out I was actually given the product number AND serial numbers for a number of servers (the spreadsheet was horribly formatted, so the two fields just looked like one big string until my afternoon coffee kicked in).

Answer (score 0):

```
$PN = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace Root\wmi MS_SystemInformation -ComputerName $PC -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ).SystemSKU

Write-host $PN
```

Comment: Consider adding some reference to this answer supporting what you state to explain why this works.

Answer (score 0):

Works on Windows 7 & Windows 10
From another user that posted. @harrymc

```
#Open Powershell and type the following. 
$Server='ComputerName'
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Server)
$regkey = $reg.OpenSubkey("HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\BIOS")
$SystemSku = $regkey.GetValue("SystemSku")

$SystemSku
```

or try

```
$Server='ComputerName'

Get-WmiObject -ClassName CIM_System -ComputerName $Server| Select-object -ExpandProperty SystemSKUNumber
```

`$Server` can be directly replaced by a ComputerName. example...

```
Get-WmiObject -ClassName CIM_System -ComputerName PC001 | select SystemSKUNumber
```

Keep in mind if you are on a domain you may need to provide credentials by either using an `invoke-command` or `-credential` parameter.

```
Get-WmiObject -Credential Domain\UserID -ClassName CIM_System -ComputerName $Server
```

or

```
Invoke-Command -Credential Domain\UserID -ComputerName PC001 -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject -Credential -ClassName CIM_System}
```

if WinRm is not configured on client, you may experience issues.

Comment: the `Get-CIMInstance -ClassName CIM_System | Select-object -ExpandProperty SystemSKUNumber` have provided me HP product number `7QE59EA#ACB` for local laptop but the HP site has accepted the `7QE59EA` only

Answer (score 0):

simply from cmd line:

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi path MS_SystemInformation
```

Comment: This is one of the things the selected answer already suggests. Please avoid additional answers unless they give substantial unique information not already given in other answers.

Comment: It actually was NOT in the accepted answer.  That's why I created another answer.  But, I did now edit the accepted answer to include it.